# how to use when a lib function has the same name with it's system call?

Tags: linux, c

code as follows, sched_yield() has the same name of lib function and system call, I don't know sched_yield() in the code is a lib function or a system call, how to distinguish?

```
#include sched.h

void shm_lock(volatile uint32_t *lock, uint32_t value, uint32_t spin)
{
    uint32_t  i, n, pid;

    for ( ;; ) {
        if (*lock == 0 && cmp_set(lock, 0, value)) {
            return;
        }

        for (n = 1; n < spin; n <<= 1) {
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                //printf("i %d\n",i);
                asm_cpu_pause();
            }
            //printf("n %d\n",n);
            if (*lock == 0 && cmp_set(lock, 0, value)) {
                return;
            }
        }

        sched_yield(); // here!!!

        pid = *lock;
        if(pid){
            if(kill(pid,0)==-1 && errno == ESRCH){   
                cmp_set(lock, pid, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the composing, I am brand new to this forum.

Answer (score 3):

If it has the same name as a system call, then it's usually your standard library's wrapper around that system call.

The musl libc standard library defines `sched_yield()` as:

```
#include <sched.h>
#include "syscall.h"

int sched_yield()
{
    return syscall(SYS_sched_yield);
}
```

(A most straightforward syscall wrapper).

There's no notational difference between function calls and system call wrappers in C if that's what you're asking.

System call wrappers are just functions (could be macros) that (usually) call the `syscall` function, which lays out its parameters to the appropriate registers and invokes the proper instruction for your architecture (`int 80h` on x86 for instance) to signal the kernel to take it from there.

Comment: It helps me, Thank you!